# How to add icon to SpringBoard with tweak

Tags: iphone, ios, tweak, logos

I would like to make an iOS tweak, which ads an icon to SpringBoard, but I can't find any solution. I found IconSupport, but I never used it, and I can't find any sample or open source project for it.
Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a .png file to your project. For iPhone it needs to be 57x57 px, and you can include a 114px version for retina if you like. Go to your app's project info (the blue icon in the navigator) then in the app info tab there are two spaces for icons. Drag the files onto the appropriate spaces and then you'll see them in springboard for your app

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but in this case I don't want to make an app, just a tweak, which adds that icon, and on press launching a process.